# Symfony3.4 : Expected X arguments. Found X

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony3.4, the following error occurred while supporting automatic wiring.
I got the following error in VSCode.
It seems that I'm getting data from the repository, but I don't know what data I'm getting.
Is there a way to check?

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html
Error

```
Expected 1 arguments. Found 0.intelephense(1005)
```

StaffEntity.php

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Lib\Parameters;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Repository\StaffRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="staff", uniqueConstraints={
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_staff_unique", columns={"staff_login_id"}),
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_image_mail_unique", columns={"image_mail"})
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Staff implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * Hash password generation
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function makeHashPassword()
    {
        if ($this->rawPassword) {

            //Error location "()"
            $encoderFactory = Parameters::getEncoderFactory();

            $this->password = $encoderFactory->getEncoder($this)->encodePassword(
                $this->rawPassword, Parameters::getParameter('staff_password_salt')
            );
        }
    }
```

Parameters.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
/**
 * Utility class to get parameters from container
 */
class Parameters
{
    private static $container;

    /**
     * Set up the container
     *
     * @param Containerinterface $container container
     */
    public static function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        self::$container = $container;
    }
   /**
     * Get encoderFactory
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory
     */
    public static function getEncoderFactory(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory)
    {
        return self::$container->get('security.encoder_factory');
    }
```

Comment: The error is because Parameters::getEncoderFactory expects an encoder factory as an argument.  Which seems strange especially since the code you posted then ignores it.  You can remove the argument I suppose.  By the way, this is another example of how the app does not do things the 'Symfony' way.  Accessing container services inside an entity is considered to be a big no no.  But it will work so continue on just realizing that eventually you will want to move this sort of stuff to some sort of user manager service.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your comment. Certainly, when I put $ encoderFactory in that part, the error disappeared. In other places, the error of "Found X ..." is displayed in the same way where the argument of Entity was passed. Do you have any idea? This is going to make a different question.

Comment: This is purely a guess but as your code is written, VSCode has no way of knowing what class $encoderFactory actually is so it cannot check the methods being called.  Maybe using some var annotations might help.